# getting null value in list when passing by ajax call to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing my list to an mvc controller but I am getting null value in the controller.But my list has values when show in alert on client side.

ajax call

```
$("#addTiles").click(function() {
    userTiles = JSON.stringify({
        'userTiles': userTiles
    });
    alert("Entered function.");
    alert(userTiles[0].TileID);
    var url = '@Url.Action("AddTiles")';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: userTiles,
        success: function(d) {
            if (d.indexOf('"IsSessionExpired":true') != -1) {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                onAddTilesSuccessful(d);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            errorInOperation();
        },
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});

function onAddTilesSuccessful(e) {
    $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append(e);
}

function errorInOperation(d) {
    $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append("Something went wrong");
}
```

mvc controller

```
  public ActionResult AddTiles(List<UserTilesVM> userTiles)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

List Model

```
public class UserTilesVM
{
    public int TileID { get; set; }
    public int TopPosition { get; set; }
    public int LeftPosition { get; set; }
}
```

List in javascript

```
"{"userTiles":[{"TileID":"3","TopPosition":0,"LeftPosition":0}]}"
```

I have also tried by sending my list with stringfy but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Any Error in `console`?

Comment: You have specified `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and `contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",` - it cant be both (ditto for `dataType`)

Comment: yeah I have mentioned it only once by mistake paste here twice

Comment: Now you have removed the `json` one (its the `html` one you need to remove since your sending `json` to the controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use : `[HttpGet]` on the method `AddTiles` as you have used `type: "GET"` on the Ajax hit.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddTiles(List<UserTilesVM> userTiles)
{
     return View();
}
```

If Still doesn't works then try `type: "POST"` on Ajax hit and on method use `[HttpPost]`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTiles(List<UserTilesVM> userTiles)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: My controller method is hit but in my list I am getting null value how to solve this problem

Comment: You are having a list of " UserTilesVM " in userTiles. ??

Comment: thanks now its workinh have used post as type and [HttpPost] on controller's action,its working now

Answer (score 5):

You have contentType and dataType twice in your AJAX setup, with different values, which will break the AJAX call.

Keep in mind contentType is to tell the server what type of data to expect and dataType is to determine what type of data is returned, from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Edit: I see you have edited your code!

In this case, since you are using JSON.Stringify to modify the data you are sending, you would use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` as your contentType, since you are sending JSON data to the backend.

Comment: yeah I have mentioned it only once by mistake paste here twice

Comment: You deleted the wrong one. Consider the type of content you are sending!

Comment: I have tried changing the contentype to json but still getting null value in list have used [HttpGet] on my controller's action too

Comment: You are POSTing with your AJAX call. Use [HttpPost]

Comment: thanks yes I have used type as post,yeah I have mentioned it only once by mistake paste here twice and [HttpPost] now,its working now

Comment: what if I want to achieve - public ActionResult AddTiles(List<UserTilesVM> userTiles1,List<UserTilesVM> userTiles2) in my controller how to send the two lists from ajax call

Comment: var data = JSON.stringify({
    array1, array2
});

and then send data

Answer (score 2):

when we are trying to pass object data using ajax, we have to store data in variable and pass data directly using "data :'variable'" in AJAX to Controller Method

```
$("#addTiles").click(function() {
   var userTiles = ({
        'userTiles': userTiles
    });
    alert("Entered function.");
    alert(userTiles[0].TileID);
    var url = '@Url.Action("AddTiles")';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: userTiles,
        success: function(d) {
            if (d.indexOf('"IsSessionExpired":true') != -1) {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                onAddTilesSuccessful(d);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            errorInOperation();
        },
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});

function onAddTilesSuccessful(e) {
    $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append(e);
}

function errorInOperation(d) {
    $("#tilesSubmissionMsg").append("Something went wrong");
}
```

//Use  [HttpPost] keyword for getting value which was passed by AJAX.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTiles(List<UserTilesVM> userTiles)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your list definition is not ok:

```
"{"userTiles":[{"TileID":"3","TopPosition":0,"LeftPosition":0}]}"
```

should be:

```
"{"userTiles":[{"TileID":"3","TopPosition":"0","LeftPosition":"0"}]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

i have using this sequence that work fine

you have check the 
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
sequence in ajax method